# How to remove leading zeroes from float value in php

Tags: php, floating-point, typeconverter

Hello
I am trying to remove leading zeroes from my float value but cannot do it.
I have a number `012.36` which I need to convert as `12.36`. I have used `ltrim` to remove leading zeroes but when I use `ltrim` the variable is changed to string and I cannot use it as a number.
When I again try to convert it to float value using `(float)` or `floatval` it again adds a leading zero to the value like `012.36`
I know it is a simple problem but can't get to solve it. Please help..

Here is the code.
I have a function which returns me the value and I have used it in a variable.
Here is my Function

```
public function getCartPercentShippingRate(){
        $shippingRateCollection = $this->getShippingMethodForShippingCountry();
        $shippingRate = 0;
        foreach ($shippingRateCollection as $shipping){
            $shippingRate = $shipping->getShippingRate();
        }
        $quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $totals = $quote->getSubtotal();
        $shippingPercent = $totals * $shippingRate/100;
        return $shippingPercent;
    }
$price = $shippingRateModel->getCartPercentShippingRate();
```

When I echo the variable using `echo $price` it displays `012.36`.

When I use `echo $price = (float)($price);` It still displays `012.36`.
I have tried this. `$newprice = ltrim($price, '0');` It displays the `$newprice` as `12.36`. But when I use it in my another function to set price like this, `$method->setPrice($newprice);` It displays me 0 as the new price.
If I use static value like `$method->setPrice(12.36);` Is displays the new price as 12.36.

Comment: PHP doesn't behave like this. Please post some code.

Comment: You sure it's not an octal number?

Comment: Yes I am sure.. Its a simple number.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not echoing 0 before echo your number?

Comment: if `012.36` is not a `string` but a `double` then it is supposed to be treated as `12.36` otherwise if it is a `string` then `ltrim()` is the best option. Check your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use (float)
```

Here is the demo

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bce5c7faaf43e33f3b3677b22de2656a87ed3fa6)

Comment: This doesn't work for cases like "0.123", hence use the most voted answer on here.

Answer (score 7):

Try this may it'll help you... First convert value into string and do this.

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```

Example

```
$val = 012.36;
$val = ltrim($val, '0');
echo (float) $val;
```

Comment: I have tried this. $newprice = ltrim($price, '0'); It displays the $newprice as 12.36. But I when I use it in my another function to set price like this, $method->setPrice($newprice); It displays me 0 as the price.

Comment: After apply this code you has to convert $val into float when you want to use it or assign value into another variable like this.

float $temp= (float) $val;

Comment: Hope you are getting me...!

Comment: I have mentioned it in the code that when I am converting it to float it again adds a leading zero. That is strange but it is happening with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have tried it. Following code gives me what want

```
$num = 012.36;
echo (float)$num; // outputs 12.36
```

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, remains? What does it mean?

Comment: @sectus, It does not remove leading zero. It displays 012.36.